# Set transparent background for ImageView to override my app theme

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget, android-theme

I have applied an **theme** for my app by defining the `android:theme` in my ***AndroidManifest.xml*** like following:

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<application
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            ...
            ...
        </activity>
        ...
</application>
```

in **themes.xml:**

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
   <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/blue_bg_img</item>
</style>
```

As you can see above in `MyTheme`, I have applied an blue color image as my app `windowBackground`. So, every view element in my app will have this blue color image background.

But I have one ImageView element which I do not want to have this blue `windowBackground`, instead, I would like to have a transparent background for it. **I tried to:**

```
myImageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

But the blue image defined in my app theme is still showing. Seems I can not override the app theme I have defined. How can I override my theme for one View element in my app ???

Comment: Well, if the window behind your `myImageView` is blue, then even if `myImageView` has a transparent background, you would still see blue behind it. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @ UgglyNoodle, you understood me correctly. So, how can I set transparent background for my imageView in my case?

Comment: So, is the purpose that you want to be able to see through your app's blue window to whatever is behind the window?

Comment: My ImageView is floating on top of my screen view, the blue background of my ImageView is not preferred, so I need to remove it, that's why I need transparent background for this ImageView.

Comment: But your entire screen view is blue, right?

Comment: Yes, entire screen view background is blue, like my theme indicates.

Comment: You say you want `myImageView` to have a transparent background. Transparent means that you can see whatever is behind it. In your case, you have a blue background behind `myImageView`. So even if it's transparent, it will appear blue. What do you actually mean when you say you want it to be transparent? What do you want the background to look like?

Comment: @ UgglyNoodle, as I said above, it is only the screen view's background in blue color, please notice, I said "background". I won't only show background on screen right? On the screen view, there are other elements on top of background, like icons. My ImageView's blue background will hide those icons partially. That's why I need to set the ImageView to transparent background.

Comment: Okay, I see. First of all, I disagree that setting `android:windowBackground` will affect the background of all your views. This attribute should only affect the window. Next, what is the drawable being shown in `myImageView`? Is this drawable transparent?

Comment: The drawable is not transparent, it is an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I managed to solve this problem myself by decreasing the height of my ImageView element until the blue background is not visible. If other people have other solutions, I am very pleased to see.

Answer (score 0):

If the background of the screen is blue, if you set the ImageView background to transparent, you'll get blue! Try setting it to Black, or whatever other color you expected to see!

Comment: Hi, set to black works, But it still does not resolve my problem. I need a transparent background for my ImageView... :(